# Что мне вводить в поля http proxy и port?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans

пытаюсь установить netbeans для c++
на официальном сайте пишут что надо заполнить эти поля
вот ссылка https://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions_ru.html

**что мне вводить в поля http proxy и port?**
[image]

Comment: выберите "No proxy"

Comment: мне это нужно для установки с++

Comment: Напиши тот адрес который твоя организация использует для выхода в интернет. Если не знаешь - спроси у админа.